# glsl light doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm working on some basic lighting in my application, and am unable to get a simple light to work (so far..).

Here's the vertex shader:

```
#version 150 core

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 pvmMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

in vec3 in_Position;
in vec2 in_Texture;
in vec3 in_Normal;

out vec2 textureCoord;
out vec4 pass_Color;

uniform LightSources {
    vec4 ambient = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    vec4 diffuse = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    vec4 specular = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    vec4 position = vec4(1.5, 7, 0.5, 1.0);
    vec4 direction = vec4(0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
} lightSources;

struct Material {
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    float shininess;
};

Material mymaterial = Material(
    vec4(1.0, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0),
    vec4(1.0, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0),
    vec4(1.0, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0),
    0.995
);


void main() {
    gl_Position = pvmMatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);

    textureCoord = in_Texture;


    vec3 normalDirection = normalize(normalMatrix * in_Normal);
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vec3(lightSources.direction));

    vec3 diffuseReflection = vec3(lightSources.diffuse) * vec3(mymaterial.diffuse) * max(0.0, dot(normalDirection, lightDirection));

    /*
    float bug = 0.0;    
    bvec3 result = equal( diffuseReflection, vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) );
    if(result[0] && result[1] && result[2]) bug = 1.0;
    diffuseReflection.x += bug;
    */

    pass_Color = vec4(diffuseReflection, 1.0);
}
```

And here's the fragment shader:

```
#version 150 core

uniform sampler2D texture;

in vec4 pass_Color;
in vec2 textureCoord;

void main() {   
    vec4 out_Color = texture2D(texture, textureCoord);

    gl_FragColor = pass_Color;

    //gl_FragColor = out_Color;
}
```

I'm rendering a textured wolf to the screen as a test.  If I change the fragment shader to use `out_Color`, I see the wolf rendered properly.  If I use the `pass_Color`, I see nothing on the screen.

This is what the screen looks like when I use `out_Color` in the fragment shader:
[image]

I know the `diffuseReflection` vector is full of 0's, by uncommenting this code in the vertex shader:

```
...
/*
float bug = 0.0;    
bvec3 result = equal( diffuseReflection, vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) );
if(result[0] && result[1] && result[2]) bug = 1.0;
diffuseReflection.x += bug;
*/
...
```

This will make the `x` component of the `diffuseReflection` vector `1.0`, which turns the wolf red.

Does anyone see anything obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If I was debugging this, the first thing I'd do would be to modify the vertex shader to say `pass_color = vec3((0.5 * normalDirection) + vec3(0.5), 1.0)`;  in effect, draw to the screen using normals as if they were RGB (scaled up so that -1..1 normal values become 0..1 color components).  That'll let you verify that yes, you have non-zero normals which are pointing approximately the right directions.  If that goes as expected, you can check your other inputs, and then the results of individual calculations, to figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: Check that dot(x,y) produces positive values -- try max(0.0f, -dot(x,y));

Comment: Had to modify it a bit to make it work on my testbed. The only real problem I found was that "uniform LightSources{..." block. It doesn't compile on my Linux NVIDIA v310.19. Had to break it out as a struct and set the struct as a uniform input. Other than that it works. It's not pretty :) but it works.

Comment: Thanks BentFX, turns out that was my problem as well - it didn't like the default values in the LightSources uniform I guess :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, try debugging incrementally.  I see a number of ways your shader could be wrong.  Maybe your normalMatrix isn't being passed properly?  Maybe your in_Normal isn't mapped to the appropriate input?  Maybe when you're casting lightSources.direction to a vec3, the compiler's doing something funky?  Maybe your shader isn't even running at all, but you think it is?  Maybe you have geometry or tessellation units and it's not passing correctly?

No one really has a chance of answering this correctly.  As for me, it looks fine--but again, any of the factors above could happen--and probably more.

To debug this, you need to break it down.  As suggested in the comments, try rendering the normals.  Then, you should try rendering the light direction.  Then render your n dot l term.  Then multiply by your material parameters, then by your texture.  Somewhere along the way you'll figure out the problem.  As an additional tip, change your clear color to something other than black so that any black-rendered objects stand out.

It's worth noting that the above advice--break it down--is applicable to all things debugging, not just shaders.  As I see it, you haven't done so here.